# Easy access Object Getter with Java

Tags: java, getter, setter

Method 1: traditional getter/setter

Toyota class:

```
public class ToyotaCar implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 2011932556974180375L;

  private int miles;

  public void addMiles(int miles){  
    this.miles = miles;
  }

  public int getMiles(){
  return miles;
  }

}
```

Human class:

```
public class Human implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1748193556974180375L;

  private ToyotaCar car;

  public void setCar(ToyotaCar car){  
    this.car = car;
  }

  public int getCar(){
  return car;
  }

  public void addCarMiles(int num){
    getCar().addMiles(num);
  }

}
```

Method 2: "other"

Toyota class: -same as above toyota class-

Additional containerHandler class:

```
public enum HumanContentsContainer {

  CAR{
    @Override public Object getContainer(){
      return new ToyotaCar();
    }
  },

  HOUSE;

  public Object getContainer(){ //because cannot be static enum constant as every human has different items
  return null;
  }
}
```

Human class:

```
public class Human implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1748193556974180375L;

  private HashMap<HumanContentsContainer, Object> contents;

  public void setContents(){  
    for (HumanContentsContainer c : HumanContentsContainer.values()){
      contents.put(c, c.getContainer());
    }
  }

  public HashMap<HumanContentsContainer, Object> getContents(){
    return contents;
  }

  public void addCarMiles(int num){
    //TODO how to replicate this: getCar().addMiles(num);???

  }

  //TODO i dont want to use the below method because whats the point of creating a whole container handler if im just going to use a traditional getter again?
  //public ToyotaCar getCar(){
 //   return (ToyotaCar) contents.get(HumanContentsContainer.CAR);
 // }

}
```

So how do I replicate the getCar().addMiles(x) method using a traditional getter without actually creating a getter?

Please note I also don't want to do this (below code): Because again, not worth it over a getter then:

```
public void addCarMiles(int num){
    ((ToytotaCar)contents.get(HumanContentsContainer.CAR).addMiles(num);

  }
```

Looking for some easy kind of usage like:

```
human.getContentsThatIsIntanceOf(ToyotaCar).addMiles(1);
```

But don't know what getContentsThatIsInstanceOf would look like

Comment: If you have a public method "addCarMiles", why won't you have a private strongly typed field "car", as in method a.? You already made the assumption that your human can add miles to a car. I would also let go of the private getters/setters, unless you do some lazy load.

Comment: because there will more than just a car, i will add more contents like house, car, shoes, clothes, and what i forgot to add in the original post pre-edit; there is a getter for the hashmap conents. So I want the usage to be as easy as getContents().addMiles(x)

Comment: Well you already proxy much of the functionality of these objects to the Human. If I would need to return a map, I would init the map with the members and return it when I need, but otherwise work with the first-class members.

Comment: Sorry, i initially wrote the getters and setters examples as private, they were meant to be public

Comment: What do you mean return the map when u need it? because the map would return an Object, not ToyotaCar, therefore you cannot do .addMiles method

Comment: here is a getter for the hashmap conents - if you for some reason need to return all the contents of the human as a map, you can use a Map<HumanContentsContainer, Object>map = new HashMap(); map.put(CAR,this.car );

Comment: You're just adding the car to the map? How do you create a getter that returns an object instanceof Toyota car, is i guess what im asking. But the only input provided to the getter method would be HumanContentsContainer.CAR (and ofcourse the map)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
public class Human implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1748193556974180375L;

private ToyotaCar car;

public void setCar(ToyotaCar car){
    this.car = car;
}

public int getCar(){
    return car;
}

public void addCarMiles(int num){
    getCar().addMiles(num);
}

public Map<HumanContentsContainer, Object> getContents(){
    Map<HumanContentsContainer, Object>map = new HashMap();
    map.put(CAR,this.car );

    //same for all the shoes and clothes and whatever the Human has
}

public void setContents(){
    for (HumanContentsContainer c : HumanContentsContainer.values()){
        switch (c){
            case CAR:{
                this.car=c.getContainer();
            }
        }
        //and so on
    }
}
```

}

**Edit**

If you need to have a *dynamic* set of capabilities, I would suggest that you indeed keep the map of objects, and get rid of the ‘addCarMiles‘ method, as it implies that every human has a car.

I would implement public method on human ‘performCommand(CapabilityType, CapabilityCommand)‘ where the command will receive the capability and perform the operation on it. You may check out the Command Pattern tutorials.

**Edit 2:**

If all you want is to create a getter which will return dynamic type, you can use generics.

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Human implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1748193556974180375L;

    private HashMap<Class, Object> contents;

    public void setContents(){
        for (HumanContentsContainer c : HumanContentsContainer.values()){
            contents.put(c.getContainer().getClass(), c.getContainer());
        }
    }

    public HashMap<Class, Object> getContents(){
        return contents;
    }

    public <T> T getContentsThatIsIntanceOf(Class<T> type){
        Object object = contents.get(type);
        if (object==null){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No such element: "+type.getName());
        }
        return type.cast(object);
    }


    public void usageExample(){
        this.getContentsThatIsIntanceOf(ToyotaCar.class).addMiles(10);

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you're missing the point, what I need is a better getter not setter. How can I create one universal getter which returns instanceof Car or instanceof House when I want it to?

Comment: @JackSmith Check out the Edit 2